# Extract id from url in select mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table let's say data.

The data table contains id and url.

```
id  url
1   https://gourmet.com/detail/12345/?where=tokyo 
2   https://dental-clinic.com/source/detail/4123/?site_code=tokyo
3   https://dental-hospital.com/detail/index/sdf2344/?where=tokyo
4   https://gourmet.com/detail/234ff/?where=tokyo
5   https://dental-clinic.com/source/detail/4123ss/?site_code=tokyo
6   https://gourmet.com/detail/43543//?where=tokyo
```

I want to get the id only inside the url during select. Like I have the regex pattern already but I want to know on how to use it on the "SELECT" mysql portion.

I have 3 url patterns.

Note: The id in the url is alphanumeric.

Note: Some url are like this. Has double slash in the far end:

https://gourmet.com/detail/12345//?where=tokyo

Desired output:

```
id  api_id  url
1   12345   https://gourmet.com/detail/12345/?where=tokyo 
2   4123    https://dental-clinic.com/source/detail/4123/?site_code=tokyo
3   sdf2344 https://dental-hospital.com/detail/index/sdf2344/?where=tokyo
4   234ff   https://gourmet.com/detail/234ff/?where=tokyo
5   4123ss  https://dental-clinic.com/source/detail/4123ss/?site_code=tokyo
6   43543   https://gourmet.com/detail/43543//?where=tokyo
```

The select sql should look like this:

```
SELECT (regex?) as api_id, id, url FROM data;
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Its mysql 5.6.42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can handle this using two chained calls to `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```
SELECT
    id,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', -2), '/', 1) AS api_id,
    url
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

The first call to `SUBSTRING_INDEX` with `-2` removes everything from the URL except for the last path element plus the query string.  The second call with `1` removes the query string, leaving us with the API id.

On speculation to your comments below, if sometimes the path separator is showing up as two forward slashes, then you could just replace all `//` with a single `/` forward slash:

```
SELECT
    id,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(url, '//', '/'), '/', -2), '/', 1) AS api_id,
    url
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: It really works!! Thank you very much. This is perfect. But unfortunately some idiot puts double slash on the url so the output is empty. Can I use OR in it?

Comment: @dummy I can only write a query for data which I can actually see.  If there be some edge cases in your data for which my query fails, then edit your question and mention those edge cases.

Comment: @dummy I fixed it, check my updated answer, and [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c37642430b25c14b519ee307049ef905) is a demo link with the updated query.

Answer (score 0):

A *brute-force* solution should be like:

1. Reverse the string (i.e, url)
2. Get first digit's index
3. Get the Substring between first digit's index and until the '/' is found!
4. Now, check if the resultant substring is contain on main string (url) or not

   4.1. If you found the substring inside of string(url), simply put on table

   4.2. Else, reverse the substring and put on table
5. Return the table

Solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction (@Url VarChar(1000))
RETURNS @TableName TABLE (Id Int Identity(1,1), apt_id VarChar(30), urlName 
VarChar(1000))
AS
BEGIN;
   Set @url = Reverse(@Url)
   Declare @i as Int = 1
   Declare @j as Int = 0
   While(Ascii(Substring(@Url, @i, 1)) >=48)
   Begin
      Set @i = @i +1
   End
   Set @j = @i + 1
   While(Ascii(Substring(@url, @j, 1)) != 47)
   Begin
     Set @j = @j +1
   End

   If((CharIndex(SubString(@Url, @i+1, @j-@i-1), @Url) = 1))
   Begin 
      Insert @TableName
      Select Substring(@Url, @i+1, @j-@i-1), @Url
   End
   Else
   Begin
      Insert @TableName
      Select Reverse(Substring(@Url, @i+1, @j-@i-1), @Url)
   End
 RETURN;
END;
```